# animation not working, loop get stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

i creat animation code for the fish to swim back and forth and he only swim 1 time and stuck
can you help pleas?

here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/qLCnT/3/

```
function anim() {
    $('#fish_1').animate({
     "left": "-90px"}, 2000, flip);
}

function back() {
    $('#fish_1').animate({
     "left": "230px"}, 2000, flipBack);
}

anim();

function flip() {
    $('#fish_1').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateY: '180deg',
        complete: back
    });
}

function flipBack() {
    $('#fish_1').transition({
        perspective: '100px',
        rotateY: '0deg',
        complete: anim
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you saw console? 'TypeError: $(...).transition is not a function'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've just forgotten to include the [transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/#top) library in your fiddle, causing the `.transition()` method to be undefined:

Example with it included: http://jsfiddle.net/qLCnT/6/

Comment: thanks a lot!!!!!!!! from where do i supposed to bring this library in real project files?

Comment: You can either download it from the official site: http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js or you can use the CDN hosted on [jsDelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!jquery.transit)